# Copying and pasting reduces the text size

Tags: bug, ios-app, fonts

Copying and pasting some text in the question body reduces the text size in editor. Preview doesn’t show any difference.

> [image: copy paste reduced]

- App Version: 1.7.0.1
- Device: Unknown (iPad7,3)
- OS Version: Version 11.0 (Build 15A372)